# Sort string data based on characters and its length

Tags: java, string

Can I get any easy way in java where I could arrange the alphabets in order where

```
a < aa < aaa < aaaa
a < b < ab < ba < aba
```

String.compareTo method will arrange data in the below format. Hence will not serve my purpose
a < aa < aaa < b < ab < ba

Kindly help!!!

Comment: You'll have to write something that serves your purpose. If after you've spent some time doing that and you have issues you can post the code and the issues here.

Comment: write a comparator that accepts two strings and outputs 0 if the strings are same, 1 if the first string is greater(Should appear later) and -1 if it should appear earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the comparator that compares the string length and use compareTo together

```
        public int compare( String o1, String o2 )
        {
            if( o1.length() > o2.length() )
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if( o1.length() < o2.length() )
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return o1.compareTo( o2 );
        }
```

Comment: Thank you both Raghav and Voe

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by using a `Comparator`

Check this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class SComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if(s1.length() != s2.length()){
            return s1.length() - s2.length();
        }
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }

}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> L = new ArrayList<String>();
// ...
Collections.sort(L, new SComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this question through **sorting** as well.

```
String[] words = {"going", "went", "go", "how", "jam"};    
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Output:

```
go < going < how < jam < went
```